# How do you list all logins for Sql Azure?

Tags: azure-sql-database, users, logins

What queries can I use to list all logins for a server and database in SQL Azure?

I tried running `select * from sys.sysusers` but I'm guessing that's just showing the users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A login is for authenticating to the server.

A login maps to a database user to access the database.

`SELECT * from master.sys.sql_logins` will list logins for Azure.

Comment: using this query SELECT * from master.sys.sql_logins I have the following error in azure database: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.sql_logins' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: you can only query master db with that select. you are querying some other db, that's why you get error